# Woocommerce - Change Widget to include Category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use woocommerce and the standard widgets are fine, but I want to add the option to show products only from a certain category. Here is the code for the standard widget:

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

/**
 * List products. One widget to rule them all.
 *
 * @author   WooThemes
 * @category Widgets
 * @package  WooCommerce/Widgets
 * @version  2.3.0
 * @extends  WC_Widget
 */
class WC_Widget_Products extends WC_Widget {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->widget_cssclass    = 'woocommerce widget_products';
        $this->widget_description = __( 'Display a list of your products on your site.', 'woocommerce' );
        $this->widget_id          = 'woocommerce_products';
        $this->widget_name        = __( 'WooCommerce Products', 'woocommerce' );
        $this->settings           = array(
            'title'  => array(
                'type'  => 'text',
                'std'   => __( 'Products', 'woocommerce' ),
                'label' => __( 'Title', 'woocommerce' )
            ),
            'number' => array(
                'type'  => 'number',
                'step'  => 1,
                'min'   => 1,
                'max'   => '',
                'std'   => 5,
                'label' => __( 'Number of products to show', 'woocommerce' )
            ),
            'show' => array(
                'type'  => 'select',
                'std'   => '',
                'label' => __( 'Show', 'woocommerce' ),
                'options' => array(
                    ''         => __( 'All Products', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'featured' => __( 'Featured Products', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'onsale'   => __( 'On-sale Products', 'woocommerce' ),
                )
            ),
            'orderby' => array(
                'type'  => 'select',
                'std'   => 'date',
                'label' => __( 'Order by', 'woocommerce' ),
                'options' => array(
                    'date'   => __( 'Date', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'price'  => __( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'rand'   => __( 'Random', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'sales'  => __( 'Sales', 'woocommerce' ),
                )
            ),
            'order' => array(
                'type'  => 'select',
                'std'   => 'desc',
                'label' => _x( 'Order', 'Sorting order', 'woocommerce' ),
                'options' => array(
                    'asc'  => __( 'ASC', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'desc' => __( 'DESC', 'woocommerce' ),
                )
            ),
            'in_cat'  => array(
                'type'  => 'text',
                'std'   => __( 'Category Number', 'woocommerce' ),
                'label' => __( 'In Category', 'woocommerce' )
            ),
            'hide_free' => array(
                'type'  => 'checkbox',
                'std'   => 0,
                'label' => __( 'Hide free products', 'woocommerce' )
            ),
            'show_hidden' => array(
                'type'  => 'checkbox',
                'std'   => 0,
                'label' => __( 'Show hidden products', 'woocommerce' )
            )
        );

        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Query the products and return them
     * @param  array $args
     * @param  array $instance
     * @return WP_Query
     */
    public function get_products( $args, $instance ) {
        $number  = ! empty( $instance['number'] ) ? absint( $instance['number'] ) : $this->settings['number']['std'];
        $show    = ! empty( $instance['show'] ) ? sanitize_title( $instance['show'] ) : $this->settings['show']['std'];
        $orderby = ! empty( $instance['orderby'] ) ? sanitize_title( $instance['orderby'] ) : $this->settings['orderby']['std'];
        $order   = ! empty( $instance['order'] ) ? sanitize_title( $instance['order'] ) : $this->settings['order']['std'];
        $cat   = ! empty( $instance['in_cat'] ) ? sanitize_title( $instance['in_cat'] ) : $this->settings['in_cat']['std'];

        $query_args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => $number,
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'no_found_rows'  => 1,
            'order'          => $order,
            'meta_query'     => array(),
            'post_type=products&cat='.$cat
        );

        if ( empty( $instance['show_hidden'] ) ) {
            $query_args['meta_query'][] = WC()->query->visibility_meta_query();
            $query_args['post_parent']  = 0;
        }

        if ( ! empty( $instance['hide_free'] ) ) {
            $query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key'     => '_price',
                'value'   => 0,
                'compare' => '>',
                'type'    => 'DECIMAL',
            );
        }

        $query_args['meta_query'][] = WC()->query->stock_status_meta_query();
        $query_args['meta_query']   = array_filter( $query_args['meta_query'] );

        switch ( $show ) {
            case 'featured' :
                $query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
                    'key'   => '_featured',
                    'value' => 'yes'
                );
                break;
            case 'onsale' :
                $product_ids_on_sale    = wc_get_product_ids_on_sale();
                $product_ids_on_sale[]  = 0;
                $query_args['post__in'] = $product_ids_on_sale;
                break;
        }

        switch ( $orderby ) {
            case 'price' :
                $query_args['meta_key'] = '_price';
                $query_args['orderby']  = 'meta_value_num';
                break;
            case 'rand' :
                $query_args['orderby']  = 'rand';
                break;
            case 'sales' :
                $query_args['meta_key'] = 'total_sales';
                $query_args['orderby']  = 'meta_value_num';
                break;
            default :
                $query_args['orderby']  = 'date';
        }

        return new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_products_widget_query_args', $query_args ) );
    }

    /**
     * widget function.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget
     *
     * @param array $args
     * @param array $instance
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        if ( $this->get_cached_widget( $args ) ) {
            return;
        }

        ob_start();

        if ( ( $products = $this->get_products( $args, $instance ) ) && $products->have_posts() ) {
            $this->widget_start( $args, $instance );

            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_before_widget_product_list', '<ul class="product_list_widget">' );

            while ( $products->have_posts() ) {
                $products->the_post();
                wc_get_template( 'content-widget-product.php', array( 'show_rating' => false ) );
            }

            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_after_widget_product_list', '</ul>' );

            $this->widget_end( $args );
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();

        echo $this->cache_widget( $args, ob_get_clean() );
    }
}
```

As you can see I've added line 70:

```
        'in_cat'  => array(
            'type'  => 'text',
            'std'   => __( 'Category Number', 'woocommerce' ),
            'label' => __( 'In Category', 'woocommerce' )
```

and also at Line 101:

```
$cat   = ! empty( $instance['in_cat'] ) ? sanitize_title( $instance['in_cat'] ) : $this->settings['in_cat']['std'];
```

The option is available in the widget to be able to entera category ID and it saves when I click the save button.

The bit I'm struggling with is actually applying the filter, you will see i've added to Line 110:

```
'post_type=products&cat='.$cat
```

and I've also tried:

```
'category_name' => $cat
```

But I can't get the filters to work. Could anyone point me in the right direction please?

Cheers
Chris

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?  https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Widget_Product_Categories.html#7-238

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product category is custom taxonomy, you need to use 'tax_query' to solve the purpose as follows,

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => $cat,
    ),
),
```

Here, $cat should be string/array of taxonomy terms.

Even you can use, woocommerce shortcode if it suites your requirement,

```
[product_category category="appliances"]
```

Here, 'appliances' is slug of product category.

Comment: Perfect, I added his code to line 110 and it now works brilliant! Thanks